# csvHelper error: the conversion cannot be performed, because of empty colums

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, csvhelper

I've tried to export the data of a csv file with c#(.NET version 4.5.2) and CSOM into a SharePoint Online list. My Problem is that I get this error:

*Exception thrown: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException' in CsvHelper.dll
Funktionäre.exe Error: 0 : Failed: The conversion cannot be performed.
Text: ''
MemberType: System.Single
TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.SingleConverter'
IReader state:
ColumnCount: 0
CurrentIndex: 11
HeaderRecord:
["ID","Anrede","Vorname","Nachname","Firma","Strasse","Ort","Postleitzahl","Land_Region","Fax","Telefon","Mitgliedsnummer","Benutzer2","Ortsgruppencode","Ortsgruppenname","Email","Initialen","Privat","Webseite","Legislatur"]
IParser state:
ByteCount: 0
CharCount: 315
Row: 2
RawRow: 2
Count: 20
RawRecord:
1;;Präsident und Max;;Hotel Nidum;Am Wiesenhang 1A;Mösern/Seefeld;6100;Österreich;;4,35E+13;;;;;info@nidum-hotel.com;P.;Aus;;2016
'Funktionäre.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Funktionäre.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Funktionäre.exe Error: 0 : Stack Trace:    bei CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DefaultTypeConverter.ConvertFromString(String text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
bei CsvHelper.TypeConversion.SingleConverter.ConvertFromString(String text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
bei lambda_method(Closure )
bei CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordCreator.CreateT
bei CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordManager.CreateT
bei CsvHelper.CsvReader.d__87`1.MoveNext() bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
bei ImportListFromCSV.Program.GetRecordsFromCsv() in C:\Users\DKienzl\source\repos\Funktionäre\Funktionäre\Program.cs:Zeile 164.
bei ImportListFromCSV.Program.Main() in C:\Users\DKienzl\source\repos\Funktionäre\Funktionäre\Program.cs:Zeile 44.
The program '[26296] Funktionäre.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).*

**Here is my code for Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;

namespace ImportListFromCSV
{
class Program
{
    const string csvPath = @"C:\Users\DKienzl\Documents\FDB\Faktuell_normalisiert.csv";
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            //Get site URL and credentials values from     config
            Uri siteUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"].ToString());
            var accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountName"];
            char[] pwdChars = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountPwd"].ToCharArray();

            //Convert password to secure string
            System.Security.SecureString accountPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
            for (int i = 0; i < pwdChars.Length; i++)
            {
                accountPwd.AppendChar(pwdChars[i]);
            }

            //Connect to SharePoint Online
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUri.ToString())
            {
                Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(accountName, accountPwd)
            })
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    //Map records from CSV file to C# list
                    List<CsvRecord> records =     
GetRecordsFromCsv();
                    //Get config-specified list
                    List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ListName"]);

                   foreach (CsvRecord record in records)
                    {
                        //Check for existing record based 
on title (assumes Title should be unique per record)
                          CamlQuery query = new 
CamlQuery();
                         query.ViewXml =     
String.Format("@<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
                             "<Value Type=\"Text\">{0}    
</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", record.ID);
                         var existingMappings = spList.GetItems(query);
                         clientContext.Load(existingMappings);
                         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                         switch (existingMappings.Count)
                         {
                             case 0: 
                        //No records found, needs to be added
                        AddNewListItem(record, spList, clientContext);
                               break;
                            default:
                                //An existing record was found - continue with next item
                                continue; 
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed: " + ex.Message);
            Trace.TraceError("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private static void AddNewListItem(CsvRecord record, List spList, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        //Instantiate dictionary to temporarily store field values
        Dictionary<string, object> itemFieldValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        //Use reflection to iterate through the record's properties
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(CsvRecord).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            //Get property value
            object propValue = property.GetValue(record, null);
            //Only set field if the property has a value
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propValue.ToString()))
            {
                //Get site column that matches the property name
                //ASSUMPTION: Your property names match the internal names of the corresponding site columns
                Field matchingField = spList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(property.Name);
                clientContext.Load(matchingField);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                //Switch on the field type
                switch (matchingField.FieldTypeKind)
                {
                    case FieldType.User:
                        FieldUserValue userFieldValue = GetUserFieldValue(propValue.ToString(), clientContext);
                        if (userFieldValue != null)
                            itemFieldValues.Add(matchingField.InternalName, userFieldValue);
                        else
                            throw new Exception("User field value could not be added: " + propValue.ToString());
                        break;
                    case FieldType.Lookup:
                        FieldLookupValue lookupFieldValue = GetLookupFieldValue(propValue.ToString(),
                            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LookupListName"].ToString(),
                            clientContext);
                        if (lookupFieldValue != null)
                            itemFieldValues.Add(matchingField.InternalName, lookupFieldValue);
                        else
                            throw new Exception("Lookup field value could not be added: " + propValue.ToString());
                        break;
                    case FieldType.Invalid:
                        switch (matchingField.TypeAsString)
                        {
                            case "TaxonomyFieldType":
                                TaxonomyFieldValue taxFieldValue = GetTaxonomyFieldValue(propValue.ToString(), matchingField, clientContext);
                                if (taxFieldValue != null)
                                    itemFieldValues.Add(matchingField.InternalName, taxFieldValue);
                                else
                                    throw new Exception("Taxonomy field value could not be added: " + propValue.ToString());
                                break;
                            default:
                                //Code for publishing site columns not implemented
                                continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        itemFieldValues.Add(matchingField.InternalName, propValue);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Add new item to list
        ListItemCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem oListItem = spList.AddItem(creationInfo);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> itemFieldValue in itemFieldValues)
        {
            if (itemFieldValues != null)
            {
                //Set each field value
                oListItem[itemFieldValue.Key] = itemFieldValue.Value;
            }
            
        }
        //Persist changes
        oListItem.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    private static List<CsvRecord> GetRecordsFromCsv()
    {
        List<CsvRecord> records = new List<CsvRecord>();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(csvPath))
        {
            var reader = new CsvReader(sr, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            records = reader.GetRecords<CsvRecord>().ToList();
        }

        return records;
    }

    private static FieldUserValue GetUserFieldValue(string userName, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        //Returns first principal match based on user identifier (display name, email, etc.)
        ClientResult<PrincipalInfo> principalInfo = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(
            clientContext, //context
            clientContext.Web, //web
            userName, //input
            PrincipalType.User, //scopes
            PrincipalSource.All, //sources
            null, //usersContainer
            false); //inputIsEmailOnly
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        PrincipalInfo person = principalInfo.Value;

        if (person != null)
        {
            //Get User field from login name
            User validatedUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(person.LoginName);
            clientContext.Load(validatedUser);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            if (validatedUser != null && validatedUser.Id > 0)
            {
                //Sets lookup ID for user field to the appropriate user ID
                FieldUserValue userFieldValue = new FieldUserValue();
                userFieldValue.LookupId = validatedUser.Id;
                return userFieldValue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static FieldLookupValue GetLookupFieldValue(string lookupName, string lookupListName, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        //Ref: Karine Bosch - https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/setting-the-value-of-a-lookup-field-using-csom/
        var lookupList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(lookupListName);
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        string lookupFieldName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LookupFieldName"].ToString();
        string lookupFieldType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LookupFieldType"].ToString();

        query.ViewXml = string.Format(@"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}'/><Value Type='{1}'>{2}</Value></Eq>" +
                                        "</Where></Query></View>", lookupFieldName, lookupFieldType, lookupName);

        ListItemCollection listItems = lookupList.GetItems(query);
        clientContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include
                                            (listItem => listItem["ID"],
                                            listItem => listItem[lookupFieldName]));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        if (listItems != null)
        {
            ListItem item = listItems[0];
            FieldLookupValue lookupValue = new FieldLookupValue();
            lookupValue.LookupId = int.Parse(item["ID"].ToString());
            return lookupValue;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static TaxonomyFieldValue GetTaxonomyFieldValue(string termName, Field mmField, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        //Ref: Steve Curran - http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013_06_01_archive.html
        //Cast field to TaxonomyField to get its TermSetId
        TaxonomyField taxField = clientContext.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(mmField);
        //Get term ID from name and term set ID
        string termId = GetTermIdForTerm(termName, taxField.TermSetId, clientContext);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(termId))
        {
            //Set TaxonomyFieldValue
            TaxonomyFieldValue termValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
            termValue.Label = termName;
            termValue.TermGuid = termId;
            termValue.WssId = -1;
            return termValue;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static string GetTermIdForTerm(string term, Guid termSetId, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        //Ref: Steve Curran - http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2013_06_01_archive.html
        string termId = string.Empty;

        //Get term set from ID
        TaxonomySession tSession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
        TermStore ts = tSession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
        TermSet tset = ts.GetTermSet(termSetId);

        LabelMatchInformation lmi = new LabelMatchInformation(clientContext);

        lmi.Lcid = 1033;
        lmi.TrimUnavailable = true;
        lmi.TermLabel = term;

        //Search for matching terms in the term set based on label
        TermCollection termMatches = tset.GetTerms(lmi);
        clientContext.Load(tSession);
        clientContext.Load(ts);
        clientContext.Load(tset);
        clientContext.Load(termMatches);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //Set term ID to first match
        if (termMatches != null && termMatches.Count() > 0)
            termId = termMatches.First().Id.ToString();

        return termId;
    }
}
}
```

**Here is my code for CsvRecord:**

```
using System;

namespace ImportListFromCSV
{
public class CsvRecord
{
    public float ID { get; set; }
    public string Anrede { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
    public string Firma { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }
    public string Postleitzahl { get; set; }
    public string Land_Region { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public float Mitgliedsnummer { get; set; }
    public float Benutzer2 { get; set; }
    public float Ortsgruppencode { get; set; }
    public string Ortsgruppenname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Initialen { get; set; }
    public bool Privat { get; set; }
    public string Webseite { get; set; }
    public float Legislatur { get; set; }
}
}
```

**And here is my App.config (but not with my real data of course):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"         
sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
    <add key="SiteUrl" value="http://myWebsite/" />
    <add key="AccountName" value="account.name@gmail.com"     
/>
    <add key="AccountPwd" value="Password123" />
    <add key="ListName" value="Funktionaere" />
    <add key="LookupListName" value="Lookup List" />
    <add key="LookupFieldName" value="Title" />
    <add key="LookupFieldType" value="Text" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Most code I got from this (I had to make some changes because its a bit older.):**
https://github.com/ALCBerry87/SPO-Import-List-CSV

**Here is the CSV-File I've been using:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVQUr3G--PXLeFF0qMO3WQmDBeMeVDEh/view?usp=sharing

I hope someone can help me

Best regards

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message lets you know what the issue is.  It is trying to convert empty text `Text: ''` into `MemberType: System.Single`.  You can either make the properties `Mitgliedsnummer`, `Benutzer2` and `Ortsgruppencode` nullable

```cs
public class CsvRecord
{
    public float ID { get; set; }
    public string Anrede { get; set; }
    public string Vorname { get; set; }
    public string Nachname { get; set; }
    public string Firma { get; set; }
    public string Strasse { get; set; }
    public string Ort { get; set; }
    public string Postleitzahl { get; set; }
    public string Land_Region { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Telefon { get; set; }
    public float? Mitgliedsnummer { get; set; }
    public float? Benutzer2 { get; set; }
    public float? Ortsgruppencode { get; set; }
    public string Ortsgruppenname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Initialen { get; set; }
    public bool Privat { get; set; }
    public string Webseite { get; set; }
    public float Legislatur { get; set; }
}
```

or you can give them a default value in mapping.

```cs
public class CsvRecordMap : ClassMap<CsvRecord>
{
    public CsvRecordMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(x => x.Mitgliedsnummer).Default(0);
        Map(x => x.Benutzer2).Default(0);
        Map(x => x.Ortsgruppencode).Default(0);
    }
}
```

I also noticed you are going to have an issue with the property `Privat`. It is a `bool` and is not going to be able to convert the value "Aus".

Comment: Thank you. But now is another problem:

Comment: `Funktionäre.exe Error: 0 : Failed: The IDCRL response header from server 'http://portal/' is not valid. The response header value is 'Negotiate,NTLM'. The response status code is 'Unauthorized'.
C:\Users\DKienzl\source\repos\Funktionäre\Funktionäre\Program.cs:Zeile 56.
The program '[3764] Funktionäre.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: You will need to ask another question for that issue.  It appears you are having difficulty with your connection to the server.  This would not be related to CsvHelper.

Answer (score 0):

The data record in the exception seems to include some invalid data:

`1;;Präsident und Max;;Hotel Nidum;Am Wiesenhang 1A;Mösern/Seefeld;6100;Österreich;;4,35E+13;;;;;info@nidum-hotel.com;P.;Aus;;2016`

Especially the value `4,35E+13`. Looks like a typical Excel/CSV conversion thing to me :)

Comment: I've changed it but unfortunately it doesnt work either. Here is the new Error: Funktionäre.exe Error: 0 : Failed: The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: ''
    MemberType: System.Single
    TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.SingleConverter'
IReader state:
   ColumnCount: 0
   CurrentIndex: 11
IParser state:
   ByteCount: 0
   CharCount: 321
   Row: 2
   RawRow: 2
   Count: 20
   RawRecord:
1;;Präsident und Max;;Hotel Nidum;Am Wiesenhang 1A;Mösern/Seefeld;6100;Österreich;;43500000000000;;;;;info@nidum-hotel.com;P.;Aus;;2016

Comment: Consider doing this step by step to see which field is causing the conversion exception.

So try to import a line where only ID and Anrede are populated and all other fields are empty. If that works, populate Vorname as well, and so on. When you identified the field that is causing the issue, check how it's exactly configured in your SharePoint list - maybe a mismatch between the field definition in your `CsvRecord` class and how it's defined in SharePoint.